# override toString() method in class Optional

Tags: java, overriding, option-type

I have an instance variable defined as:

```
final Optional<myClass> myOptional;
```

I would like to override its `toString()` method so that instead of returning `"[Optional(the value)]"` it simply returns `"(the value)"` (or something else if it's empty). But I can't create a subclass of `Optional` since it is apparently final. How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GhostCat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38793940/1441122) is correct in that you cannot subclass `Optional` and override its `toString` method. However, you can probably get the effect you want by writing this:

```
String myString = myOptional.map(MyClass::toString).orElse("(empty)")
```

This sets `myString` to the result of the value's `toString` method if a value is present, otherwise it substitutes the string `(empty)` if the value is absent. Of course, you can put whatever substitute string you want there.

`Optional` is final so that it will be easier to convert into a *value type* in a future version of Java. See [Project Valhalla](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/valhalla/) for information about value types, in particular [State of the Values](http://cr.openjdk.java.net/~jrose/values/values-0.html) for an overview and background.

`Optional` is also intended to be immutable, so subclassing must be prevented. See Bloch, *Effective Java*, Item 15.

Answer (score 2):

You can't.

There is no way of changing the behavior of methods of a class from **outside** its source code. So, the only choices you got are:

1. Turn to the source code of that class and make changes there
2. Extend the class, override the method and then use objects of the derived class

In your case, both options not possible. Sorry, end of story.

(yes, other, interpreted languages would allow you to do so; but Java does not).

Comment: Thanks. I wonder why the Java designers made Optional a final class.

Comment: Hard to say; but probably the point is that Optional might be coming out of many standard library calls. So it might not be so helpful to be able to override it ... as most of the time, it is not your code creating Optional objects.